# Surveys on pseudo-random number generator design?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, pseudorandomness

I am interested in generation of pseudo-random numbers for cryptography. Besides Chapter 5 of [Menezes/Oorschot/Vanstone](http://www.crcpress.com/ecommerce_product/product_detail.jsf?catno=8523&isbn=0000000000000&parent_id=&pc=); Chapter 8 of [Stinson](http://www.crcpress.com/ecommerce_product/product_detail.jsf?catno=C5084&isbn=0000000000000&parent_id=465&pc=); and Chapter 3 of [Goldreich](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1167785/?site_locale=en_GB), where else could I find more? I'm interested in general principles for designing PRNGs (desirable properties, tests, etc).

Comment: Not on design per se, but you may be interested in Goldreich's newer book: http://books.google.com/books?id=9k6Lw2U2XCkC

Comment: @S Huntsman: thanks a lot for that! I didn't know Goldreich had a book on PRNGs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to check out

- Chapters 5 and 6 of [Katz and Lindell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584885513)
- [Pseudorandomness](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/pseudorandomness/) by S. Vadhan
- [Parwise Independence and Derandomization](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/BOOKS/TCS003-1.pdf) by Luby and Wigderson
- [Pseudorandomness and Combinatorial Constructions](http://arxiv.org/abs/cs.CC/0601100) by Trevisan
- Goldreich's [webpage](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/pp_pseudo.html) on pseudorandomness, where he has pointers to other sources.

Comment: Most of this is not very relevant to practical implementations of PRNGs for cryptography.  This is not a good set of resources to give an implementor.

Answer (score 4):

If you are thinking of implementing your ideas, there is a standard battery of tests that PRNG implementations are given.  These tests (DIEHARD and successor DIEHARDER) may be downloaded from [its archived webpage](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906073813/http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/) and http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php respectively.

Comment: Important cautionary note: passing DIEHARD does not mean your PRNG is any good.  This is not a resource I would give to an implementor who needs to implement a secure PRNG.

Answer (score 1):

Are you interested in implementing a PRNG?  If so, your best bet is not to design one yourself, but just use a standard one.  /dev/urandom is the right answer on most platforms.  If /dev/urandom doesn't exist, generating a random AES key with /dev/random and then running AES-CTR mode to generate lots of pseudorandom numbers is another reasonable approach.

I recommend that you read Cryptography Engineering, by Ferguson, Schneier, and Kohno.  It is an excellent book.  It will teach you a lot about how to design and build real cryptosystems.

If you actually have to build a system that will be deployed in practice, I recommend that you do not take your guidance from the theoretical CS community, but rather from the community of practitioners and practice-oriented researchers.  Much of the theoretical CS work will not be very relevant, or potentially even misleading, to practical implementation of a secure PRNG.  I also encourage you to look at the IT Security stack exchange for those kinds of questions.

Comment: The question explicitly says he is interested in general principles, and the question was asked on the Theoretical CS stack exchange...